# ionic cordova cordovaDevice not working properly

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ngcordova

I am creating an Ionic app that needs to reference iOS and Androids device UUID.

From my understanding when using these Cordova plugins, the device needs to load the app first and then you can reference the cordovaDevice.getUUID().

I am running this on the sign in/ sign up page, which is the first page of my app.

Here is part of my login controller:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
    console.log(device.cordova);
    $scope.id = $cordovaDevice.getUUID();
    return $scope.id;
}
```

Above that code I have $scope.id = "1";
I am returning $scope.id so I can post it to an api end point.
When I load the ios app on my device, the first time I run the app it works. id is equal to the devices actual ID.
If I reopen the app it never works again, id stays equal to 1.

Comment: put it on angular.run like                                                                                                       var myId=1; angular.run(function($cordovaDevice) {myId=$cordovaDevice.getUUID(); }

Comment: @AnujGupta then how would I use $scope.id in my controller? Wouldn't I need to make it rootscope? Or can I use run directly in my controller?

Comment: have you installed cordova device plugin ? If its installed then only `$cordovaDevice` will be accessible

Comment: @HardikVaghani Yes its installed. If it wasn't I'd get a dependency error

Comment: Then try wrapping timeout on `$cordovaDevice.getUUID();` may be its taking some time to get UUID ?

Comment: you can use that $scope.id directely in which  controller you want to use. angular.run() works on app load ,

Comment: @HardikVaghani that works too!

Answer (score 0):

So after further researching I've found that since I'm trying to load the cordova device function on my first view we end up with a race condition.

I got this answer from [Raymond Camden](https://www.raymondcamden.com/2014/08/16/Ionic-and-Cordovas-DeviceReady-My-Solution/)

"Angular is going to display your view and fire off ionicPlatform.ready asynchronously. That isn't a bug of course, but it raises the question. If you want to make use of Cordova plugin features, and your application depends on it immediately, how do you handle that easily?

what I did was to add an intermediate view to my application. A simple landing page. I modified the stateProvider to add a new state and then made it the default. In my ionicPlatform.ready, I use the location service to do a move to the previously default state."

So I implemented a "Loading" view that says loading and uses state.go after 1000 milliseconds to transition to my sign in page.

Comment: You can also just wrap $cordova.getUUID(); in a timeout function and this works too, thanks @hardikvaghani

Answer (score 0):

```
var id=1;
angular.run(function($cordovaDevice) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    id= $cordovaDevice.getUUID();
}
}
```

Now you can use it anywhere in other controller like

```
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaDevice) {
 console.log(id);
})
```

Comment: When doing this I get "device is not defined" and "id is not defined".

Comment: Have you installed plugin from **cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-device**